# software-verification vs program verification

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have the tags

- [program-verification](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/program-verification) and
- [software-verification](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-verification).

Both seem to mean the same thing and should therefore be merged. Please vote on the two answers below which one you think should be the main tag (by upvoting).

If you think we need both tags, please add an answer with your reasoning.

Please vote until Friday, June 1st.

Comment: We also have [tag:formal-methods] now, which is yet another flavor of the same thing?

Comment: [tag:formal-method] is broader. Program/software verification applies formal method to a model that's detailed enough to be an implementation.

Answer (score 6):

[software-verification](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-verification) should be the main tag.

Comment: Would side with the first comments by Dave Clarke in the other post. Software verification as opposed to hardware verification gives a good intuition.

Answer (score 4):

[program-verification](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/program-verification) should be the main tag.

Comment: I prefer this one because "software" feels a bit too wide in scope.

Comment: Program verification is what they did in the 80s and 90s. Software verification is what they do in the 00s and 10s.

Comment: @DaveClarke: Isn't that an argument to have both tags? Or do they describe the same thing?

Comment: It's supposed to be an argument that program verification is out of date, based on the idea that software is bigger than programs.

Comment: Now after talking someone who does verification, he says he prefers "program-verification". So I retract my comments.

Comment: While I think it would be nice if the tags had a specific and well defined meaning, for now I view the tags as a means to finding related questions and answers. As such, I think that if the wiki info for the tags is completed and that there is no clear separation between the two, then one tag should be left with a redirect to the other. I would really prefer just one, verification, but this is not a site for me but for all of us.

Comment: @GuyCoder Having only [tag:verification] is an option, but I don't know whether that would be too broad. I agree: [tag:program-verification] and [tag:software-verification] *seem* to be used synonymously here, so there should be only one (the other as alias). This question was to choose which should survive, but there was no clear voting result.

Comment: @Raphael I was not really voting for any of them, not even my own preference. My intent was to point out that maybe we should not focus on which one was chosen, but to point out that the tags are more of a means to an end, in this case finding related questions, and that as long as the goal was the same, the path did not matter. However for new people we should try to define them in the wiki and give redirects to the other to show that we ourselves are not sure and that both are equally valid when searching for related questions and answers.

Comment: @GuyCoder In principle, I agree. However, we should do you best to avoid situation where we use a tag in a "wrong" way so it becomes inappropriate when we grow/expand. Refactoring then is hard, choosing a good tag now is simple (in principle).

Answer (score 0):

[formal-verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) is another option.

Comment: This is more general than the other two as it applied to more than programs/software.

Comment: @Raphael, yes, I only mention this since the wikipedia articles for the other two redirects to it.