# Can program-verification be made a synonym of software-verification?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

This was already suggested in [this 2012 question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385/software-verification-vs-program-verification), with the top answer being to make software-verification the main tag.

Maybe someone with 2500 rep can propose the synonym/merge? Or, answers arguing why they should not be merged would be welcome.

Comment: Relatedly on meta, probably `retagging` and `tag-pruning` should be deleted or made synonyms :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fell through the cracks. Nobody ever made the argument that they should be different, I know the topic and I can't spot any difference as to how these tags are used, so I've merged them.